# Move data by intent without startActivity

Tags: java, android

I have 2 Activities. On 2nd activity i have data which i want to move by button "Back" to 1st Activity.

Usually i moving by something like this:

```
button12.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        pass=editText2.getText().toString();

        Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("pass_value", pass);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```

But now i dont want to start Activity, instead of this i want close Activity, so i need to use `finish()`

Currently i created this, but no working:

```
b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("number", numberOfTrue);
        finish();

    }
});
```

I need something more in this code, but i dont know what.

Comment: Make a seperate class or shared preference to store the data and retrieve it later on activity u need. Using intent will create a new activity.. so creating new instance is not a good approach

Comment: obvious choice is `startActivityForResult`

Answer (score 1):

Start a new activity with

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("pass_value", pass);
 startActivityForResult(intent,1)
```

You can use setResult method to acheive your desired result

```
Intent output = new Intent();
output.putExtra("number", numberOfTrue);
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, output);
finish();
```

get Your result in FirstActivity

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        int num = data.getIntExtra("pass_value");

    }
}
```

Comment: Block of code with setResult is also needed? Is there only 1 and 3 blocks of code?

Comment: you show 3 block of code, "Start a new activity with", "You can use setResult method to acheive your desired result" and "get Your result in"

Comment: yes , with that you can get what you want, whats problem in that

Comment: "int num = data.getIntExtra("number");" something is wrong here - Intent cannot be aplied to (String) and (Int)

Answer (score 0):

b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
public void onClick(View view) {

    finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("number", numberOfTrue);  }});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open by function **startActivityForResult**
startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode)

And get the data returned in the function
**onActivityResult**

As an example you can see a face to the camera for a picture